# Sending CAN frame via UDP in Python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, udp, can-bus

I made UDP socket connection between two Linux machines and can send for example `b"Hello, World!"` easily. But now I need to send the below CAN frame

```
from can import Message
send_msg = Message(data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

So if I print `send_msg` it shows:

```
Timestamp:        0.000000    ID: 00000000    X                DLC:  5    01 02 03 04 05
```

I want to get this printed on the receiving end. The sending and receiving end codes I am using are below:

**Sending:**

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "10.140.189.249"
UDP_PORT = 5005
from can import Message
send_msg = Message(data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

print(send_msg)
MESSAGE = send_msg

print("UDP target IP: %s" % UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port: %s" % UDP_PORT)
print("message: %s" % MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Here I know `MESSAGE = send_msg` is wrong.

**Receiving**

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    rec_msg, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("received message: %s" % rec_msg)
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

As the physical layer of an UDP connection and a CAN connection are substantially different, you cannot send the CAN frames over UDP.  What is of course possible is to send the payload of the CAN frame and assemble the CAN message on the receiving side: I.e. on the sending side:

```
sock.sendto(b“12345“, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

And on the receiving side:

```
msg = Message(data=bytearray(recv_msg))
```

Most likely you do not only want to transfer the data of the CAN frame, but also the ids and other fields.

Another possibility would be to pickle the Message object on the sending side and unpickle it on the receiving side using `pickle.dumps` and `pickle.loads`

All features of the CAN bus like arbitration, error-frames etc. cannot be mimicked on a UDP connection.

Comment: So with the pickle.dumps and pickle.loads, is it possible to send CAN IDs?

Comment: I am confused here. So should I remove the "from can import Message" section from my code? As it is only the payload I need, so I should just send an array [1 2 3 4 5].

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Just send the array over the UDP connection. On the receiver side, you take the data and create the `can.Message` there. When you need more than the CAN payload, you could create the `can.Message` on the receiver pickle the complete object (not only the payload), send the pickled data over UDP and unpickle at the receiver so that you get bet the `can.Message`

Comment: But is there anyway I can extract the array `[1 2 3 4 5]` from `send_msg = Message(data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` and then use `pickle.dumps` on that array to send?

Comment: You can do `send_msg.data` to get the payload. As that is already a `bytearray`, there is no need to pickle that. You can send it directly.

Comment: Great it works. One last question. At the receiving side, I am getting `(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05')` . How can I convert it to `[1 2 3 4 5]`

Comment: Just  convert it to a list, e.g. `list(received_data)`

Comment: If I want to send the CAN IDs & other fields, do I need to send them as separate payloads? I tried `pickle.dumps` on `send_msg` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think that is more suited for a new question. „Does not work“ without details is not really a base for a helpful answer. In general, whatever needs to be available on the other side, needs to be transferred. Either individually or as a packet.